# How to read/update object instances converted into JSON from Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently stuck at the process of retrieving classes stored as JSON in firebase (I converted each instance of the object into JSON & stored it). My primary objective is to read a piece of data(at meeting which is also a JSON object) within a JSON object (`meeting`) stored as value in Firestore, using nodejs in Cloud Functions, as I am trying to create a push notification with FCM.

The code I have:

```
    exports.meetingsUpdate = functions.firestore.document('/meetings/{meetingId}')
        .onWrite(async (snap,context) => {
            var data = snap.after.data()
            data = await data.meeting;
            const obj = await data.meeting;
            const uids = await obj.groupUID;
            const requestor = await obj.requesterName;
            const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Meeting request',
                body: 'You have a meeting request from ' + requestor
            }
        }
        for (uid of uids) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
            const doc = await admin.firestore()
                        .collection('userNotificationTokens')
                        .doc(uid)
                        .get()
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
            const token = await doc.data().token
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
            const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("Message sent successfully!", res.body) 
            });
        }
        return null;
    

        })
```

Here is how my database mapping looks like [image: with 'meeting' attribute representing an JSON object]

I'm relatively new to Firebase & its functionality and have been stuck with errors like

> *SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0*

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupUID' of undefined*

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined*

for quite sometime despite trying various approaches & tweaks.

The first meeting value is a JSON object, and the second meeting attribute is also a JSON object. Apologies for the somewhat convoluted storage of data.

Comment: Is the ``{meetingId}`` thing a typo?

Comment: Nope, my intention is to listen for any new document additions to the meetings collection & then read off a specific bit of data within a JSON object stored as one of the document's values.

Comment: the value of data here has changed `data = await JSON.parse(data.meeting);' but at
            'const obj = await JSON.parse(data.meeting);` it looks like you are expecting data has the same structure

Comment: Yep you're right! Have updated the code to reflect the changes, apologies for the confusion!

Comment: That is what I mean. It should be a template string literal with ``${meetingId}`` to format the string with the variable, {meetingId} is incorrect syntax afaik.

Comment: Please follow this official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) in order to see how to read/update